Blazor And .Net Web API Relation
I'm having difficulty choosing between the advantages and disadvantages of the scenarios I'm about to mention. I need feedback on which architecture to choose for my .NET application, using N-Tier Architecture and writing the frontend part with Blazor.

Do you think I should integrate the frontend (Blazor) directly with the business layer? All Dependency Injection processes will be configured within the Blazor project.
Should I expose the business layer with .NET WebAPI and integrate the frontend with the API?

I need an opinion about architecture.

Blazor will be your presentation layer regardless. If you are using server-side Blazor you should just access your next layer, if you are using WASM Blazor you should have a WebAPI as your presentation layer for your server side and your WASM Blazor app would make calls to that.

Option 1 is only possible with Blazor Server. ViewModels might still be a good option but yes, you can directly call services.
Option 2 is required for Blazor Wasm and optional for Blazor Server.
What you pick depends entirely on what other requirements you have.
